# With ActiveRecord has_many through relationships how do I delete associations while keeping objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails how do you delete a has-many through association while retaining the formerly associated objects?  Is there an ActiveRecord way to do this or I do need to write the SQL?

Also is it possible for the objects to remain friends once the relationship is gone? [ <-- lame joke attempt]

Comment: What do you mean by remain friends?

Comment: That was a joke.  Relationship humour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself.  [collections.delete](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) and just have to make sure dependents are not set to be deleted or destroyed.  Somehow asking the question publicly seems to lead to me figuring the answer out in about 10 minutes on my own.

Comment: Can you add more information? I'm actually interested in the reverse case, I want the referenced items to be deleted. PS: Hi Carol!

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow asking the question publicly seems to lead to me figuring the answer out in about 10 minutes on my own.

That's because writing it down traverses a different neural pathway, one that apparently has other connections/associations in your mind.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: That was almost sixyears ago; I almost made it past the statute of limitations.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class A  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :b
end

Class B  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
end
```

A.b.delete  - deletes the association

A.b.destroy - deletes the association an the Associated objects (b)